# How can I stop using sudo?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto a raspberry pi.  The default user was ubuntu which I had to set up a password for.  However, for most things, I need to do sudo, and now that I am trying to work with Rails and having to `gem install` items, this permissions issues has become a roadblock that using `sudo` is not working on.

How can I either make my user "ubuntu" the root/act as sudo (not sure how to phrase this hope the meaning is conveyed), or how could I log in as root?

Comment: Both your alternatives are Bad Ideas. Work towards resolving your "roadblock".

Comment: Any idea why I have to use sudo for everything?  Is that normal?

Comment: You don't need to use sudo for *everything* but for each action that is supposed to performed by root.

Comment: I was sooo close to voting you down... I am trembling. Then I remembered that I was once a noob too.  ;-)

Comment: Have you considered using `sudo -i`? This way you have root priviledges without the need to prepend `sudo` to every single command.

Comment: Yea I've been using Ubuntu about a day and a half now so apologies.  I mean I try to do things like `nano somefile.txt` and I can' write the file out due to a permissions error, I need to do `sudo nano` - this is expected behavior?

Expected not in the sense that it makes sense given my current permissions, but expected in the sense this what I would expect to have to use `sudo` for someone who should have the hightest permissions possible for this system, even if it's not using root directly due to that being a bad idea, but the highest acceptable level.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to get used to using `sudo`, it means **S**uper **U**ser **Do** and it's like having to enter the admin password on Windows, it's a fact of life.

Are you wanting to install gems as your user (`ubuntu`), rather than on the system generally? This is explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596273/install-gem-in-local-folder

Answer (score 1):

## Options

- Run as root: this is a bad choice, unless the processes are FULLY automated, and you can easily reset the state of the machine. By Easy I mean so easy that you do it a lot, and think nothing of it.
- Set `sudo` up to allow no-password. See caveats above.
- Discover why you need `sudo`, what permissions or capabilities are needed. Then fix the problem.

E.g. if you are installing software, does it need to be installed globally, or can it be installed just for the one user.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the file when doing `visudo`

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Because you said **raspberry pi** and you're doing whatever you're doing where on that kind of hardware, you may not need full blown linux security; there's nothing wrong with opening things up in linux when on a workbench setting.  Just realize once you start networking and others can get either physical or network access then you have a potential security problem

Simply add the line

```
ubuntu    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

you can also replace `ubuntu` there with the word `ALL` which then effectively lets any account in linux do anything without a password prompt just like root.  There is nothing wrong with understanding and freely stating this, everyone should understand there sudo file and recognize what's written in it and what should, and should not, be there.

I am not familiar with ubuntu linux.  I do not know if there is an *autologin* or *passwordless login* feature; I would expect it to allow one to log in as `root` having typed a password for that account.  Linux distributions vary as to the default level of security they employ upon installation (n character passwords, complexity, etc.)  That can all technically be undone, while frowned upon 9 out of 10 times, in a workbench setting yes it can be done.

> Any idea why I have to use sudo for everything? Is that normal?

yes that is normal.  That is the default level of security that all linux distributions these days employ by default after installation expecting the computer to be connected to the internet.  For a rpi, on a workbench setting, yeah you can relax some of that security stuff to make things easier.